# How to get the Nth next weekday that is also not a holiday given a date

Tags: sql, date, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, user-defined-functions

Given a date input, I am trying to write a udf that gives back the nth next weekday that is also not in a list of holidays I am getting from another table.

My holiday table MY_TABLE looks like

| holiday_date | holiday_name |
| --- | --- |
| '2023-07-04' | 'Independence Day' |
| '2023-12-25' | 'Christmas Day' |
| '2023-04-07' | 'Good Friday' |

etc...

So for example if I am given the date 2023-06-30, and N = 10 (so the 10th weekday), I would like to get back '2023-07-17' since this ignores Saturday and Sunday and also July 4. I don't want a stored procedure, I am trying to do this as a udf.

So far I have

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_NTH_WEEKDAY(DATE_INPUT VARCHAR, NTH_DAY INTEGER)
RETURNS DATE
AS
$$
SELECT 
    DATEADD(DAY, 1 * VALUE, TO_DATE(DATE_INPUT, 'YYYY-MM-DD')) AS MY_DATE, 
    DAYNAME(MY_DATE) AS DAY_OF_WEEK
FROM TABLE (FLATTEN(INPUT => ARRAY_GENERATE_RANGE(1, NTH_DAY, 1)))
WHERE DAY_OF_WEEK NOT IN ('Sat', 'Sun') 
$$;
```

But I am not sure how to check that the dates in between that range I get back are weekends and/pr holidays and skip over them to get the nth day...is there a way I can do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So just trying to solve this is SQL first (in fact I plan to ignore the UDF part).

a CTE for holidays:

```
with my_table(holiday_date, holiday_name) as (
    select * from values
    ('2023-07-04'::date, 'Independence Day'),
    ('2023-12-25'::date, 'Christmas Day'),
    ('2023-04-07'::date, 'Good Friday')
)
```

When can roll out 2x to number of days (every 5 days will have 2 weekend days, and an assumption of ~1 holiday per week), and then join that to the my_dates, then classify the values, and then number the wanted ones:

```
SELECT 
    '2023-06-30'::date as date_in,
    10 as NTH_DAY,
    DATEADD(DAY, VALUE, date_in) AS MY_DATE, 
    dayofweekiso(MY_DATE) as dow,
    mt.*,
    dow < 6 as week_day
    ,week_day AND mt.holiday_date is null as to_count
    ,row_number() over(partition by to_count order by my_date) as rn
FROM TABLE (FLATTEN(INPUT => ARRAY_GENERATE_RANGE(1, NTH_DAY*2, 1)))
LEFT JOIN my_table as mt on mt.holiday_date = MY_DATE
order by my_date
;
```

gives:

| DATE_IN | NTH_DAY | MY_DATE | DOW | HOLIDAY_DATE | HOLIDAY_NAME | WEEK_DAY | TO_COUNT | RN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-06-30 | 10 | 2023-07-01 | 6 |  |  | FALSE | FALSE | 1 |
| 2023-06-30 | 10 | 2023-07-02 | 7 |  |  | FALSE | FALSE | 2 |
| 2023-06-30 | 10 | 2023-07-03 | 1 |  |  | TRUE | TRUE | 1 |
| 2023-06-30 | 10 | 2023-07-04 | 2 | 2023-07-04 | Independence Day | TRUE | FALSE | 3 |
| 2023-06-30 | 10 | 2023-07-05 | 3 |  |  | TRUE | TRUE | 2 |
| 2023-06-30 | 10 | 2023-07-06 | 4 |  |  | TRUE | TRUE | 3 |
| 2023-06-30 | 10 | 2023-07-07 | 5 |  |  | TRUE | TRUE | 4 |
| 2023-06-30 | 10 | 2023-07-08 | 6 |  |  | FALSE | FALSE | 4 |
| 2023-06-30 | 10 | 2023-07-09 | 7 |  |  | FALSE | FALSE | 5 |
| 2023-06-30 | 10 | 2023-07-10 | 1 |  |  | TRUE | TRUE | 5 |
| 2023-06-30 | 10 | 2023-07-11 | 2 |  |  | TRUE | TRUE | 6 |
| 2023-06-30 | 10 | 2023-07-12 | 3 |  |  | TRUE | TRUE | 7 |
| 2023-06-30 | 10 | 2023-07-13 | 4 |  |  | TRUE | TRUE | 8 |
| 2023-06-30 | 10 | 2023-07-14 | 5 |  |  | TRUE | TRUE | 9 |
| 2023-06-30 | 10 | 2023-07-15 | 6 |  |  | FALSE | FALSE | 6 |
| 2023-06-30 | 10 | 2023-07-16 | 7 |  |  | FALSE | FALSE | 7 |
| 2023-06-30 | 10 | 2023-07-17 | 1 |  |  | TRUE | TRUE | 10 |
| 2023-06-30 | 10 | 2023-07-18 | 2 |  |  | TRUE | TRUE | 11 |
| 2023-06-30 | 10 | 2023-07-19 | 3 |  |  | TRUE | TRUE | 12 |

so we can see the answer is the 17th of July 2023.

There is the question of if holidays roll forward, here in New Zealand, if the holiday occurs on the weekend it moves to the next Monday, so that would complicate this answer a little.

But we can simplify the SQL down to:

```
SELECT 
    DATEADD(DAY, VALUE, '2023-06-30'::date /*DATE_INPUT*/) AS MY_DATE
FROM TABLE (FLATTEN(INPUT => ARRAY_GENERATE_RANGE(1, 10/*NTH_DAY*/*2, 1)))
LEFT JOIN my_table as mt
    ON mt.holiday_date = MY_DATE
WHERE dayofweekiso(MY_DATE) < 6 
    AND mt.holiday_date is null
QUALIFY row_number() over(order by my_date) = 10/*NTH_DAY*/
;
```

[image]

which you can jam into a UDF, and most likely discover they don't work how you want in Snowflake.